# Match an item with specific attribute BUT NOT with a second attribute

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to select these HTML elements:

```
<div class="blue">
```

but not these:

```
<div class="blue" style="font-weight:normal;">
<div class="blue" style="margin:5px;">
<div class="blue" style="text-decoration:none;">
etc.
```

In practice I would like to select all the DIVs with only:

```
class="blue"
```

and not the DIVs that has both:

```
class="blue" AND the 'style' attribute inside
```

where 'style' may not always be the same (see above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**  for css selector, in case you are able to use it too..:

xpath:

```
//div[@class="blue"][not(@style)]
```

css:

```
div:not([style])
```